# Division by two of functions in #P

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes, counting-complexity

Let $F$ be an integer valued function such that $2F$ is in $\#P$.  Does it follow that $F$ is in $\#P$?  Are there reasons to believe this is unlikely to always hold?  Any references I should know about?

Somewhat surprisingly, this situation came up (with a much larger constant), for a function $F$ for which $F \in? \#P$ is an old open problem.

**Note:** I am aware of the paper M. Ogiwara, L. Hemachandra, [A complexity theory for feasible closure properties](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/002200009390006I) where a related division-by-2 problem has been studied (see Thm 3.13).  Their problem is different however, as they define the division for *all* functions via the floor operator.  That allowed them to make some quick reductions to parity problems.

Comment: I don't even see an answer for the cases in which ​ Range(F) = {0,1,2} . ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: Isn't #P closed under polynomial-time reductions?

Comment: @Kaveh: If $f(x)$ is a $\#P$ function, and $g(y)$ a poly-time function, then $f(g(y))$ is in $\#P$, but $g(f(x))$ not necessarily (presumably). For example, there seems to be no reason why all nonnegative GapP functions should be in $\#P$, but they are reducible to $\#P$ in this way.

Comment: @RickyDemer: Do you see the answer when Range(F) is just {0,1}?

Comment: @JoshuaGrochow : ​ Yes, it's "Accept if and only if you guessed both 2F witnesses in lexicographic order". ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer: Oh right. Duh :).

Comment: @JoshuaGrochow If you do division with NO floor function then ${\bf PP}$ collapses to the following complexity class, which I just defined, via Theorem 5.9 on TCTC book.  ${\bf UPPX} = \{ L |$ there is a polynomial-time predicate P and a polynomial q such that, for all $x$,
$\bf 1.$ $x \not \in L \Rightarrow ||\{y|$ $|y|\leq q(|x|) \wedge P(x,y)\}|| < 1$  $ \bf 2.$ $x \in L \Rightarrow ||\{y|$ $|y|\leq q(|x|) \wedge P(x,y)\}|| \geq 1$$\}$ Then one needs to show where ${\bf UPPX}$ belongs in the complexity hierarchy. It is hopefully the case that ${\bf UPPX} = {\bf PP}$

Comment: @TayfunPay: For the question at hand, you need to not just consider "division with no rounding" but "division by 2 under the assumption that the number being divided is even."

Comment: @TayfunPay : ​ There's presumably a typo, since you gave the definition of NP. ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: How hard is it to tell whether a function in #PP is always even? I expect it's undecidable.

Comment: @PeterShor : ​ ​ ​ That's certainly undecidable. ​ One can take a machine that accepts if and only if the counting witness is all 1s and the same length as the input and M halts in exactly [that length] steps. ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Answer (score 4):

I try to give my intuition why I think this is unlikely to hold. Take your favorite problem in $PPA$, and convert it into a problem in $\sharp P$, e.g., our function $f$ can be the number of Hamiltonian cycles in an input 3-regular graph containing a certain fixed edge. From the parity argument we know that $f$ is always even, so you can define $F:=f/2$ and I see no reason why $F$ would be in $\sharp P$.

Comment: Okay. Now I'm confused. Doesn't $K_4$ have three Hamiltonian cycles?

Comment: Okay ... I've checked. The theorem is that every ***edge*** appears in an even number of (undirected) Hamiltonian cycles in a 3-regular graph, not that there are an even number of Hamiltonian cycles total. So the right counting problem is: given a three-regular graph and an edge $e$, let $f$ be the number of Hamiltonian cycles in $G$ that go through $e$. Is $F/2$ in #P?

Comment: Indeed, funny that no one noticed earlier... I've added it.

Comment: Although generally I agree with your intuition, in this case, I think $f/2$ may actually be in #P: Let e=(v_1,v_2) be the edge in G. Let u,w be the neighbors of v_1 that aren't v_2. The following NP machine has f/2 accepting paths: guess a Hamilton cycle that includes the pair of edges (u,v_1) and (v_1,v_2). (The point is that the proof of even parity creates a bijection between such Ham. cycles and those that includes (w,v_1) and (v_1,v_2).) So for the intuition to work you need something in PPA that goes via e.g. a counting argument, or that avoids some easy bijection...

Comment: @Joshua After Peter's comment, I've also checked the proof fearing that the situation might be what you write, but I don't think it is. Maybe there are different proofs? Could you link to the one you are referring to? I am just following the one that's on page 501, figure 1 here: https://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~christos/papers/On%20the%20Complexity.pdf

Comment: In fact, your claim would imply that the number of H cycles is the same through any edge of the graph, which is probably not true, though now I cannot find a counterexample.

Comment: @domotorp: (1) p. 641 here: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022000098916117. (2) How does my claim imply that the number of cycles is the same through any edge? I agree that the latter fact is probably not true. Perhaps we should continue this in chat and then come back with the answer?

Comment: @Joshua (1) I couldn't find any mention of your claim there. (2) If there are $2k$ H cycles through an edge, then there are $k$ H cycles through the edge and any of its neighboring edges. But then there are also $2k$ H cycles through this neighboring edge etc. we are done using connectivity.

Comment: @domotorp: I agree with your reasoning in (2). (1) is not stated explicitly there, but I *thought* follows from the proof on p. 641. However, I agree that it seems unlikely that there is always the same number of Ham. cycles through every edge. I will have to think about this some more to see whether I've made a mistake, or if this seemingly unlikely fact is actually the case.

Comment: The fact is not true. For instance, it is easy to check that it fails for all connected 3-regular graphs on 8 vertices (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_simple_cubic_graphs#8_nodes for a list), except for the cube (which is edge-transitive).

Comment: @JoshuaGrochow Do you know if the answer to Igor Pak's question is YES?

Comment: @Turbo I believe it is still open; they just posted a paper that discusses this and related issues https://arxiv.org/abs/2204.13149

Comment: @Turbo I believe their Proposition 7.5.5 gives an oracle separation; that is, a function F such that 2F is in #P^A but F is not.